# Listening to keyboard on Mac using Python and encountering AttributeError: CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to find a way to quantify how often I'm distracted.  However, flawed the following technique is, it is at least better than nothing.  I've decided I'm going to try to count the keystrokes and mouse clicks in my computer. I can listen to my mac keyboard when I run the following python code provided I do so from `Mac Terminal` and use `sudo`:

```
import keyboard
def count_key_strokes():
    while True:
        b = keyboard.read_key()
        print (b)
```

However, the `keyboard` module is not written for mouse clicks on a Mac, so I have to use a different module, which is the following:

```
from pynput import mouse
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if not pressed:
        return False


def count_mouse():
    d = 0
    while True:


        with mouse.Listener(
                on_click=on_click,
                ) as listener:
            listener.join()
            d += 1
            print (d)
```

In order to run the two programs simultaneously I have to thread them together like so:

```
import threading
''code here
threading.Thread(target=count_mouse).start()
threading.Thread(target=count_key_strokes).start()
```

However when I run that code from `Terminal` using:

```
sudo python3 count_keystrokes.py
```

I get the following error message and do not understand why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 292, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 431, in listen
    KeyEventListener(callback).run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 366, in run
    loopsource = Quartz.CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(None, self.tap, 0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 163, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource
```

---

UPDATE

The real program is only slightly more complicated.  The real program keeps track of time and only counts keystrokes and mouse clicks when a certain app is frontmost.  In any case, invariably after 20 minutes my computer (MacBookPro 2015) slows down intolerably.  It is certain that it is this program that is to blame because when I terminate it, everything return immediately to normal.  My first workaround was to reset the program every 2 minutes, but that did not work.  The computer still slows down intolerably after 20 minutes.

```
import keyboard, threading
from pynput import mouse
import time
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
#
totals = []
clicks = 0

def count_keystrokes():
    global clicks
    keystrokes = 0
    elapsed = 0
    minutes = 0
    total_elapsed = 0
    all_time = lambda x, y, z: y + (z - x) if x != 0 else 0

    while True:
        active_app = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()
        front_app = active_app["NSApplicationName"]
        if front_app == 'PyCharm':
            if elapsed == 0:
                elapsed = time.time()

            b = keyboard.read_key()
            keystrokes += 1

        else:
            if elapsed > 0:
                total_elapsed += (time.time() - elapsed)
                elapsed = 0

        if all_time(elapsed, total_elapsed, time.time()) > 30:
            minutes += 1
            print (f"{minutes}  {keystrokes + clicks}")
            # print (keystrokes + clicks)
            total_elapsed = 0
            elapsed = 0
            keystrokes = 0
            clicks = 0



def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if not pressed:
        return False


def main():
    global clicks
    time1 = time.time()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=count_keystrokes)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()


    while True:
        clicks = 0
        with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
            listener.join()
            frontmost = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()
            if frontmost["NSApplicationName"] == 'PyCharm':
                clicks += 1
            if time.time() - time1 > 120:
                return


    thread.join()


while True:
    main()

    print ('main program exited')
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

UPDATE

The problem is certainly the threading.  The program run with just the keyboard listening works fine and does not slow the computer down.

Comment: Does the main script also contain a loop? If not then it may be exiting and you may be losing scope somewhere. You'd probably want to keep a reference to both threads and make them daemons as a start.

Comment: I'm not that advanced of a programmer.  I just learned what a daemon was 3 days ago and have forgotten already.  You're going to have to dumb things down a little bit if you want me to understand you.

Comment: Do your functions both run properly if you don't put them in threads?

Comment: I guess I wasn't very explicit when I wrote: "I can listen to my mac keyboard when I run the following python code provided I do so from Mac Terminal and use sudo."  So let me rephrase that to: "The following python code works without error."  In other words, yes, both functions work fine alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `pynput.keyboard.Listener` and `pynput.mouse.Listener` are subclasses of `threading.Thread`, so you do not need to explicitly use threads at all.

The `with` statement, as is noted in [the documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#pynput.mouse.Listener), is simply short hand for:

```
listener.start()
try:
    with_statements()
finally:
    listener.stop()
```

and not necessary.

A simplified version of your script might be written thus:

```
from pynput import keyboard, mouse


def on_press(key):
    # A key has been pressed
    pass


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        # A mouse button has been clicked
        pass


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as kl, \
        mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as ml:
    kl.join()
    ml.join()
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your main script might be finishing quickly and your threaded scripts are continuing to run in the background. If that is the case then you should try setting up threading in a more robust way to keep the main thread alive:

```
import threading
from time import sleep
''code here
t1 = threading.Thread(target=count_mouse)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=count_key_strokes)
t1.daemon = True
t2.daemon = True
t1.start()
t2.start()

# prevent the main thread from exiting
while True:
    sleep(0.05)
```

**Edit:** After a closer look at the `pynput` module, which natively uses threading, you probably don't need to add a thread for it too. So a complete solution could look like (untested):

```
import keyboard
from pynput import mouse

def count_key_strokes():
    while True:
        b = keyboard.read_key()
        print (b)

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('clicked')

thread = threading.Thread(target=count_key_strokes)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()

thread.join()
```

Note that `pynput` can also listen for keystrokes, so you could use it for everything.

Comment: Can you post your entire script so it can be run the same?

Comment: Give me about 8 hours. The code is working when it is minimal but when I add stuff to it it breaks, so let me try to figure out what additional lines are causing it to break.

Comment: I got it working. I will also trying to determine which app is frontmost since I only want to count keystrokes when I'm using a certain app.  It took me a long time to figure out what the problem was.  I had to gradually add to the correct code bit by bit and run to see if an error appeared.  What happens was that when you run the line which determines which app is frontmost outside the `with` statement then that throws the error. I would explain things in more detail but stackoverflow makes it too difficult to explain things in comments.

Comment: Actually, the program slows my computer down too much.  It works for about 10 minutes then things start to grind to a halt.  Do you know how I can stop that?  Maybe I can just run the program for 5 minutes than stop it for 5 seconds, before starting it again.

Comment: You can always edit your original question if you need to add more details or change code.

Comment: I made an update.  My hunch is that it is the threading that is slowing things down and in my update the threads are still running when I exit `main()`.  Perhaps I could terminate the threads?  I'm trying to figure out how to do this but not having much luck.

Comment: Also I didn't see the comment about pyinput listening to the keyboard.  I tried that but I find with statements very bizarre and I do not understand them.  Pyinput listens to keystrokes using a `with` statement.